# Jhipster installed by npm fails to start

Tags: jhipster

I installed Jhipster using npm, on WSL.
When I launch Jhipster, I get the following error message:

```bash
$ jhipster
(node:19323) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not supported
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/cli/jhipster.cjs:24:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/cli/jhipster.cjs:25:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
(node:19323) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:19323) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried to:

- install again (sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster)
- relaunch wsl
- install jhipster version 7 instead of 8

but the error is still raising.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of Node are you using? JHipster 7 requires Node 16, while JHipster 8 has a min version of Node 18.

Comment: thanks @MattRaible
I had an older version of Node, I upgraded and now JHipster runs fine.